# Iran place names in Farsi

Tags: data, internationalization, gazetteer, iran

I'm looking for a downloadable listing of place names for Iran, in Farsi script.

- I downloaded [GeoNames for Iran](http://geonames.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.html#I), but many of the place names in there seem to be only in Latin script (of 253,000 names, 100,000 are in Farsi script).
- OSM has been suggested by Brad, to be queried using Overpass (Turbo). But I'm not sure whether it's possible to extract places *in a particular country*. Some tags like `is_in` or `is_in:country` are helpful, but are not consistently used. Maybe there's a relation I need to find?
- [Global Gazetteer from Falling Rain Genomics](http://www.fallingrain.com/world/IR/) seems to have lots of data from several public sources, including 200,000 place names in Roman script and 200,000 in Farsi and/or Arabic. But I don't see any way to extract the data other than web-crawling/scraping.

Comment: You could probably get an extract from OSM (e.g. via overpass-turbo)

Comment: @BradHards, thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how to get Overpass to return only places in a given country? I've used filter clauses like `[is_in ~ "Iran$|ایران$"]`, but this clearly misses a lot of places. A bbox would give more places, but not restricted to Iran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the OSM query, this will get you pretty far:

```
[out:json][timeout:50];
area[int_name="Iran"][boundary="administrative"]->.a;
(node["place"]["name"](area.a);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I got 13220 nodes returned this way via [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9Wz). You could also do the same things for ways or relations, and/or modify the key query (such as using "name:fa", although it seems like most nodes have the name key in farsi)

One more thing, you can view just the name tags, as well as specify names in a particular language via the [Multilingual Maps Test](http://mlm.jochentopf.com/).